# ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expressionSQL state: 21000 Why and how it happens?

Tags: postgis, spatial-join

I want to update an empty column with a join :

```
UPDATE icpe_modifie
SET region =
(SELECT nom_reg_m FROM icpe_modifie as icpe 
JOIN regions as reg 
ON ST_WITHIN(icpe.geom, reg.geom))
```

`icpe_modifie` is a point table and `regions` is a polygonal table.
I want to add the name of the region where is located the point.
But it returns :

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expressionSQL state: 21000
```

So I tried :

```
SELECT nom_reg_m FROM icpe_modifie as icpe 
JOIN regions as reg 
ON ST_WITHIN(icpe.geom, reg.geom)
```

This second query is well executed and no error is raised.

The current solution I chose is to `LIMIT 1` :

```
UPDATE icpe_modifie
SET region =
(SELECT nom_reg_m FROM icpe_modifie as icpe 
JOIN regions as reg 
ON ST_WITHIN(icpe.geom, reg.geom) LIMIT 1)
```

But I would like to better understand the error statement, to it means that join returns for at least one row several items.
I do not understand how a point could be in two different areas. And I also would like to check the points for which this is happening and have no idea to find these trouble points.

Comment: Are you looking for an explanation of why one-to-many joins fail in sub-queries ([dba.se]) or how to address situations where point-in-poly returns multiple rows ([gis.se])? Right now you've asked the Question to address the former.

Answer (score 2):

I made a mistake while building my query.
I am running an `UPDATE` and a `JOIN`.

The proper way to do is :

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.c1 = new_value
FROM t2
WHERE t1.c2 = t2.c2;
```

See more [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/).

I was trying to fit the whole result in each single row.